# Pipe into `adb shell`

Tags: android, pipe, adb

Why can I not pipe into `adb shell`?

```
[klm@kth ~]$ echo foo | adb shell cat
^C
```

The above command hangs on my 4.0.1 emulator, and I'm not seeing the expected `foo` output.

I presume it's because `adb shell` doesn't pipe its stdin into its child-process' stdout, and `cat` sits and waits forever. Has this really not been implemented in `adb`, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 9):

An alternate option may be to use adb port forwarding and netcat.

Set Android side to recieve:

```
busybox nc -lp 5555 > piped_file.txt
```

PC side, set forwarding and send:

```
adb forward tcp:4444 tcp:5555 # Anything sent to localhost 4444 will be forwarded to Android 5555
cat piped_file.txt | busybox nc localhost 4444 # Pipe through the port to Android
```

The PC netcat connects to the Android netcat through the forwarded port, and the `piped_file.txt` is delivered.

---

Additional Info
Combined with tar, you can copy entire directory structures onto your device.

`busybox nc -lp 5555 | tar -x # Android side`

```
adb forward tcp:4444 tcp:5555 # PC side
tar -c directory | busybox nc localhost 4444
```

Comment: I like that you can copy entire dirs with tar, but with tcp forward it's two commands and not just one like it should be...

Answer (score 4):

This is correct. This functionality has not been implemented.

Update:

A lot of bugs have been fixed and new features implemented in `adb` since the time the original question had been posted. Including support for proper `stdin` handling by `adb shell`. So there is no need for the `netcat` workarounds anymore.

Comment: I find that strange! It's such basic functionality, and wouldn't seem hard to implement. Am I missing something?

Comment: it's really true ... it doesn't create an "interactive shell" (reading from stdin) when there are arguments to `adb shell` as shown [here](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/commandline.c#L1204).

Comment: Neither `adb shell` nor `adb shell` with arguments have proper stdin handling, try `echo date | adb shell` and `echo foo | adb shell wc`. Neither produce the expected output, need to kill the process using Ctrl-C. Tested with `adb version` => `Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
Revision 3db08f2c6889-android` on Linux.

Comment: @ack, `echo foo | adb shell wc` produces the result I expected. Either your device is too old or you have wrong expectations

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Put the following into the `adb_shell.sh` file and use it instead of `adb shell`:

```
#!/bin/bash

adb forward tcp:12345 tcp:12345
adb shell busybox nc -lp 12345 -e "$@" &
sleep 1s
exec nc -q 1 localhost 12345
```

This creates an `nc` listener which runs the specified command upon the connection, and then connects to it.

Comment: I guess this won't work if you start running multiple `adb shell` commands simultaniously. Neat Hack, though :)

Answer (score 1):

Try that:
`echo foo | adb shell cat -`

`cat file | adb shell "cat - > file.txt"`

`cat file | adb shell md5sum`