# reading input interactively from "adb shell <command>"

Tags: adb

When I run `adb shell "read VAR?PROMPT"` on my computer, I get the `PROMPT`, but nothing I type seems to actually be sent to the remote shell (I have to press Ctrl+C to kill the `adb shell` process). It works when I use an interactive shell, so it looks like `adb shell <command>` maps only `stdout` and not `stdin`.

Is there some workaround I can use to send input into a non-interactive command?

Comment: it would help if you'd describe your use case in greater detail. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I wrote an interactive script on the Android phone which uses `read` to pause at various points and also to read variables at a certain point. I used to call this script from an interactive `adb shell`. Now I want to call the (remote) script from a local script that does some things automatically prior to running the script (e.g. pushing files), but the interactive script no longer works.

Comment: you will have to rewrite your remote script logic to run completely on the PC side instead.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been here for quite some time, but I found myself with the same problem (different use case though) and I could find a suitable solution for my specific case.

If the solution suggested in this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278587/pipe-into-adb-shell) does not work for you (for 
me it did not), the following analysis got me to my own answer.

If you browse through the source code of adb (I used [this one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/adb/) for this answer) you will see that in commandline.cpp the implementation is different for the case "adb shell" depending on the number of arguments (either only "shell" or "shell  [args]"). The following code fragment from that source file shows it (within function adb_commandline):

```
//[...]
if (!strcmp(argv[0], "shell") || !strcmp(argv[0], "hell")) {
    char h = (argv[0][0] == 'h');
    if (h) {
        printf("\x1b[41;33m");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    if (argc < 2) {
        D("starting interactive shell\n");
        r = interactive_shell();
        if (h) {
            printf("\x1b[0m");
            fflush(stdout);
        }
        return r;
    }
    // non-interactive shell. Here the arguments after "shell" are parsed.
    // [...]
}
```

That means that adb runs only interactively when the command line was "adb shell", and non-interactively when having more arguments.

Therefore, you need to change the source code to make adb treat any "shell" as interactive, regardless of the amount of arguments after "shell".

I hope this helped you approach a solution to your use case.