# How to create a bat file for running executable in ADB shell that takes in further user input

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, adb

I am new to writing bat files and currently, I am creating a bat file to access the adb shell and run an executable inside it. For example, I want to run HelloWorld.exe which is inside the adb shell. Moreover, I do not have permission to edit the Helloworld.exe to receive input parameters instead of user input.

HelloWorld.exe:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string name;
    int age;

    cout << "Enter your name: ";
    cin >> name;

    cout << "Hello, " << name << "!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

To just run the HelloWorld.exe itself, I am familiar that we can use:
`adb shell Helloworld.exe`. However, how should we pipe the input to the executable, I have tried using echo (`echo good_guy | adb shell Helloworld.exe`) but it is not working.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30798253/) explain it well enough for you?

Comment: The file extension `.exe` is only used by Windows executables. adb shell allows you to connect to Android devices which run Linux. Linux can not execute Windows executables. You can cross-compile your C code to ARMv7/armv8a CPU and to Linux ELF to create `Helloworld` executable.

Comment: What @Robert says is true and very possible in your case. However, nothing prevents to give your executables an `.exe` extension on linux too.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to create bat file, you can create a bash file like below to run in side adb shell. E.g: file of `script` which contain below line

```
echo "Arg1 is $1, arg2 is $2"
```

$1 is your 1st argument

$2 is your 2nd argument

And put it in your device folder (/data/local/tmp/). Then run it with adb shell like below

```
adb shell '/data/local/tmp/script a b'
```

The result after running above should be

```
Arg1 is a, arg2 is b
```

Answer (score 0):

This works as expected

```
echo world | adb shell 'read v; echo "hello $v"'
hello world
```

so yours should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help! In the end, we use `adb shell "(echo test1; echo test2) | /usr/bin/path_to_bin"`. This is similar to @Diego Torres Milano suggestion of piping the input